# Check in an Array if I have three same values, without knowing the value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array with random numbers, from 1 to 6.
How can I know if I have in this array two, three or four same numbers ? And what is that number ? Or if I have two numbers that they appear twice ?

```
array = [1, 3, 5, 5, 6];    

x = array[0];
repetitions = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
const y = array[i];

if (x === y) {
    repetitions++;
  }
}
```

Should I do something like this for each element of array ?

Thank you!

Comment: do you have only one multiple number, or more?

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple solution that can be provided using filter;

```js
var array = [1,2, 3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4, 5, 5, 6,6,6];
var duplicate = [];
var newArray = array.filter((v, i) =>{ 
 if(array.indexOf(v) == i){
  return v
}else{
  duplicate.indexOf(v) == -1 ? duplicate.push(v):'';
}
})

console.log(`new array ${newArray}`);
console.log(`Duplicate values array ${duplicate}`);
```

Comment: it doesnot work if there are more than two duplicate values

Comment: @MaheerAli fixed

Comment: @MaheerAli thanks for the tip `new Set()`, :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some constraints you should clarify. For example, this code would returns the first number in the array that is duplicated:

```
let duplicated = [...array] // makes a copy of the array
                   .sort()  // since `sort` mutate the original
                   .find((item, index, arr) => value === arr[index + 1]);

console.log(duplicated) // 5, in your case
```

If there is no number duplicated, then it will return `undefined`.

However, maybe that is not what you want. Considering this array: `[1, 3, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]`. Even if there is also `6` duplicated, you will always return `5`.

If you want just to know if there is at least a number duplicated, the code above will works. If you want to know all the duplicated number, and in which order they appear first in the original array, you need something different. For example:

```
let array = [1, 3, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6];
let occurrences = array
                    .reduce((acc, value) => (acc[value]=-~acc[value], acc),{});

console.log(occurrences); // {"1": 1, "3": 1, "5": 2, "6": 4}
```

At this point you can decided what do you want to do with this data, e.g. you can filter out the numbers that appears in the array just once:

```
console.log(
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(occurrences).filter(([num, count]) => count > 1)
  )
); // {"5": 2, "6": 4}
```

etc.

**UPDATE (see comments):**
`Object.fromEntries` is a method recently introduced, in case having a filtered object with all the occurrences is the goal, in this context could be easily replaced by a function like this:

```
const fromEntries = entries => 
  entries.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => (acc[key] = value, acc), {});
```

Comment: Yep, I think this is the best solution ! Bravo !

Comment: But why I receive "Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'" ?

Comment: It might be very possible that the engine you’re using do not support `Object.fromEntries` yet, it’s very recent: you can either use a 3rd party polyfill, a transpiler such Babel, or recreate the object yourself in a similar way I did with the first `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

You check if the value in array exists more than 2 times by compare `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` the value

```js
function duplicates(arr){
  let result = []
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if(arr.indexOf(item) !== arr.lastIndexOf(item)){
      result.push(item)
    }
  })
  return [... new Set(result)];
}
console.log(duplicates([1,2,3,5,5,6,6,6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and count all occurences of the values.

The result is an array where the first element is the value and the second is the count of the value.

```js
var array = [1, 3, 5, 5, 6],
    counts = Array.from(array.reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 0) + 1), new Map));
    
console.log(counts);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```